# Remove hanging objects after controller is destroyed in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, object, memory-leaks

I work on a web app that uses ng-include and angular-routes for changing pages. 
As I told in title, the issue is that some used objects remain in browser memory after page has been changed and page's controller is destroyed. In the fallowing example, I present a simplified version of controller and object that we used. This is the manner that our team of developers wrote controllers:

XController object remains hanged in memory after the page, that is controlled by MyController, is changed, using angular-routes. But, when page is changed using ng-include, the memory is cleaned up, and XController object is removed from memory.

```js
controllers.controller(MyController, function () {

    function XController() {
        console.log("In controller");
    }

    var xController = new XController();

    /** return controller instance */
    return xController;

});
```

PS: We used this type of writing code for controller because, somewhere in code we used:

```js
/** attach logging mechanism */
LoggerAspect.applyTo(xController);
```

**Edit:** @toskv LoggerAspect is a service in our tracing module.

part of code from LoggerAspect

```js
//An aspect contains advices and the target to apply the advices to.
   var aspect = new Aspect.Aspect([beforeAdvice, afterReturning, afterThrowing])
   return {
        /**
         * Applies the aspect to the passed object
         */
        applyTo: aspect.applyTo.bind(aspect)
   };
```

Aspect is a factory and Aspect is a function inside factory.

I also tried to eliminate LoggerAspect from Controller, and the XController object remains hanged in memory.

Comment: what does the  LoggerAspect do? If there is nothing more to the XController  than this the problem is most likely there.

Comment: @toskv LoggerAspect is a service in  our tracing module.

Comment: the interesting part is how it gets an instance of xController, and what it does with it. It might be that it keeps references to the controllers somehow even after they have been destroyed.

Comment: All this seems best suited for a decorator on top of the controller function that just adds the logs. :)

Comment: I tried reproducing it, so I made a small plunkr with a component that has a controller defined like yours. While profiling it doesn't seem to be leaking. Either my attempt is wrong or the problem comes from somewhere else. http://plnkr.co/edit/vI77wr4PnGiNvGMQRA4H

Comment: @toskv Finally, we solved this issue. You was right regarding to controllers with your plunker. This type of pattern doesn't create any memory leaks and our problem was in a ModelCache service and in our custom observer/subscribe classes. We took every leaked controller, one by one, and we tried to eliminate any reference from outside to hanged objects or parameters from controller.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution :)

Comment: @toskv As I told you, we took one by one, every controller and we removed reference to other objects from other controllers or services, when controller is destroyed.

At this moment, I don't know how to remove TaskModel hanged object. His reference in TaskManager keeps TaskModel in memory. Can anyone help me to understand this type of reference?
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vbLr.jpg

Comment: it's probably best to make a new question with the new info you got from the investigation :)